# Factorizing math expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I would like to ask for your guidance, to factorize the following ones:

$(A.)\quad x^2(y+z)+y^2(x+z)+z^2(x+y)+2xyz \\ $
$(B.)\quad x^2(y-z)+y^2(z-x)+z^2(x-y)$

I tried to find the common factor in Each expression, but it was inevitable.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you put dollar signs around your expressions (and remove the asterisks), they will look a lot nicer, e.g., x^2*(y+z) becomes $x^2(y+z)$.

Comment: Note to The Demonix: https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/08/28/fish/

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Each expression is a quadratic in $x$, e.g.,

$$x^2(y+z)+y^2(x+z)+z^2(x+y)+2xyz=(y+z)x^2+(y^2+z^2+2yz)x+(y^2z+z^2y)$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. As a piece of general advice, your questions will be better received if you use TeX to make them easier to read, and also if you describe in more detail what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative hint: try putting $y=-z$ in (A). What does that tell you? Similarly, try putting $y=z$ in (B).